# Failing to run wkhtmltopdf on shared host

Tags: linux, wkhtmltopdf

This is the first time I am using wkhtmltopdf.

Works fine on my Windows local pc, but I can't make it work on the live Linux shared host server.

I tried all kinds of solutions I found on google but nothing works.

I am a windows user, so I don't know anything about Linux, but I do have SSH access to the host server and the host confirmed that this is the right file to use on their server.

First I got the file, and then I tried to extract it with no success:

```
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz

tar xvjf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

tar -xvjf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

tar xvJf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
tar (child): xz: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

So I extracted the file on my local windows machine.

I manually created these folders on the host server:
usr/local/bin.

I uploaded the 2 binaries files from my local machine to this bin folder.

And I tried a few ways to test it:

```
./wkhtmltopdf-amd64 http://www.example.com example.pdf
-bash: ./wkhtmltopdf-amd64: No such file or directory

/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 http://www.example.com ex.pdf
-bash: /wkhtmltopdf-amd64: No such file or directory

./wkhtmltopdf http://www.example.com ex.pdf
-bash: ./wkhtmltopdf: No such file or directory

/wkhtmltopdf http://www.example.com ex.pdf
-bash: /wkhtmltopdf: No such file or directory
```

Please, can someone help me make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure wkhtmltopdf binary has executable permission. Assuming you have copied them into /usr/local/bin

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

then run

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --version
```

Comment: Thx, tried that: chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf And got:
chmod: cannot access `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf': No such file or directory
Maybe I put the usr/local/bin folders in the wrong place? In cpanel I see it under: /home/mysite/ ?

Comment: extract to anywhere, identify the path using pwd command then comment here. I will update answer.

Comment: ok, pwd gives me: /home/mysite. chmod usr/local/bin/wkh.... did not give any error. The permissions on the file are 775. Running usr/local/bin/wkh... --version gives: Segmentation fault

Comment: Went into the bin directory and tried wkht... --version Got: command not found

Comment: which version are you using wkhtmltopdf 32bit or 64bit? what is your server's architecture? try uname -a

Comment: uname -a: Linux rs03-pta.za-dns.com 2.6.32-673.8.1.lve1.4.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 10 08:57:30 EST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
And I downloaded the 64bit version:wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz

Comment: It appears the file I uploaded was corrupted. The host extracted it for me and now we can run it through SSH. I now had to change my code to call the file like this: /home/mysite/usr/local/bin/wk... instead of just /usr/local/bin/wk.... Thank you so much for all the help